# Jquery Easy Slider Not preloading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, opencart

I'm using Easy Slider : http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

Integrated it well on my open cart 1.5.1 installation.

I've set it to continuous scroll but the problem is, when you reach the last image and still click on the next arrow it takes a few seconds before the first image shows up again.

I'm not sure, there could be a delay or something but I couldn't see it on the source code.

Here's the site I'm using it on (refer to Best Seller Section):

http://goo.gl/f4Xi0

Comment: Jackson is correct..  easySlider only prepends/appends one element on to either side of the list to enable smooth continous transitions...  When you have an element smaller than the width it will not reset the position until you move to the first/last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your getting that delay is because the plugin was build for use with images that spanned the entire width of it, yours are small.

I'd recommend you look at a different plugin, unless you want to completely re-work this one. Here's one that's made to support a continuous flow of thumbnails, like you want:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/